# Visualising Audio From SoundCloud's Custom player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, soundcloud

I would like to know if it is possible to visualise audio from soundcloud's custom player:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player#

At the moment I could only think about using videos, but I would like to know if it is possible to do with javascript or jQuery, maybe there are some cool libraries out there?

**EDIT:**
So far this is the only exact thing I found that does exactly what I want, but I am having trouble in understanding how it works, I was trying to play around with source code but had no luck ;/ and I don't wan't to copy it exactly. Maybe you could explain principle behind it and suggest how to change it's appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check here: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/05/08/sound-visualisation-vuemeter-in-webgl/

or you can search other Web Audio Api examples for Chrome and Safari and Data Audio API for Firefox